# Getting buttons side by side with 100% Labels

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have my buttons side by side instead of stacked. Currently, They're each wrapped in a label with 100% width - I'd like them to be evenly
spaced.

```
        <div className="row">  
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div className="cs-row">
          <label className="cs-acr-listing-feature">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={"Buyers"}
              defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked}
              value={this.state.checkBox}
              onChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <i className="acr-feature-check fas fa-check" />
            I'd like to buy!
          </label>

          <label className="cs-acr-listing-feature">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={"Sellers"}
              defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked}
              value={this.state.checkBox2}
              onChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange2}
            />
            <i className="acr-feature-check fas fa-check" />
            I'd like to sell!
          </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS (ACR-LISTING-FEATURE is the limiting factor)

```
.acr-listing-feature {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #101737;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That said, since your inputs are inside the labels this will need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple, you can utilize [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label class="child">
    <input type="checkbox">
    I'd like to buy!
  </label>
  <label class="child">
    <input type="checkbox">
    I'd like to sell!
  </label>
</div>
```